# How to stop Google App Engine Launcher logging the whole html content?

Tags: google-app-engine

I use the following code to use webapp2

```
import webapp2
from webapp2_extras import i18n, jinja2
class Test(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    @webapp2.cached_property
    def jinja2(self):
        # Returns a Jinja2 renderer cached in the app registry.
        return jinja2.get_jinja2(app=self.app)

    def render(self, _template, **context):
        # Renders a template and writes the result to the response.
        rv = self.jinja2.render_template(_template, **context)
        self.response.write(rv)
    def get(self):
        self.render('index2.html')
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/',Test)], debug=False)
app.run()
```

To be simple, we just make index2.html is full of 1000 `test`

If you run it, you will find that the Google App Engine Launcher log windows is full of `test`.

It's rather terrible when you are debugging a real website.

But I find that if index2.html contains just few words like 10 `test`. The `test` will not appear in logging window.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are running two separate instances of your application.

The first is running through the development server, the second is actually running and outputting to the terminal. You can see this by adding a log output to your application. You can see that when you go to your site, the log is written two twice.

You can fix this by removing the line:

```
app.run()
```

This is not necessary when running on App Engine. Your `app.yaml` file references the app directly:

```
handlers:
- url: .*
script: guestbook.app  # Notice the .app here.
```